# How to Calculate the Contact Point between Ray and Plane

Tags: xna, vector, intersection

Is there any quick way to find the intersection point between Plane and Ray?

Comment: Try googling "line plane intersection"

Comment: An intersection between a Vector3 and a Plane doesn't make sense. You can find the intersection between a Plane and a line segment, a ray, or a line, but all of these require not one, but two Vector3's to be represented. Or you can check if a certain Point *lies* on the Plane or not. Which of these are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am using the Vector3 as a Direction , Mmm  it should be a Ray not a Vector3

Comment: http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html

Comment: long story short, study linear algebra

Comment: You should update your question to reflect that you're looking for an intersection with a ray. And since you tagged the question as XNA, you might want to add a mention to that in the body of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following method which relies on XNA's built in Math API to intersect a `Ray` and a `Plane` and get back the point of intersection:

```cs
Vector3? GetRayPlaneIntersectionPoint(Ray ray, Plane plane)
{
    float? distance = ray.Intersects(plane);
    return distance.HasValue ? ray.Position + ray.Direction * distance.Value : null;
}
```

The method returns `null` if there's no intersection, or the point of intersection otherwise.

Comment: thanks very much :) , i thought it returns just a boolean